# Fetch image from url and get its height/width

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web

I am getting an image from an url with this function:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

function getImageFromUrl(url) {
   return fetch(url).then((response) => response.blob());
}
```

For getting the dimensions of the images I am using the "image-size" library.

```
const sizeOf = require("image-size")

const image = getImageFromUrl("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/78/0c/39/780c392f5c48ee7bb99136cd34f63dcc.jpg")
const dimensions = sizeOf(image);
```

But I am getting this error: **invalid invocation at imageSize**

I think that this is because the blob is just binary data and not a file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are calling the library in wrong format.

`const sizeOf = require('image-size');`
`const dimensions = sizeOf(image);`

or for one line
`const dimensions = require('image-size')(image);`

Comment: In my code was like this require('image-size')(image); but I copied it bad here. The error persists.

Comment: I think that I have to convert the Blob to an Image File with the same properties but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

so i see you tagged reactjs & web if you want to do this in web (because your code is in nodejs ) you can put it in an img tag like this and get width and height of that tag...

if you don't want to show it just  do this in css: (dont use display: none;)

```
elem {
  visibillity: hidden;
}
```